# Can I make a programm that downloads and stores images in my pc based on an account or a hashtag?

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

Title says it all if I can I want to know how I am a noobie in programming and I have never attempted anything like that before.
Thanks,Manos

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community Manos.
please give a more detailed question next time.

this article will help you out 
https://rudrastyh.com/instagram/get-recent-photos-php.html